# No setter method in class when using PropertyUtils.setProperty

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

When I try and use Apache beanUtils to set a date property in my bean it fails with "No setter method in class".  Non-date properties are set correctly.

The following code fails with `Property 'availableFrom' has no setter method in class 'class com.brightgreenstar.entities.CapitalAsset'`

```
if (value instanceof String){
    if ((key.equals("lastUpdatedDate")) || (key.equals("availableFrom")) || (key.equals("availableTo"))|| (key.equals("purchaseDate"))) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ");
        Date date = df.parse((String)value);
        PropertyUtils.setProperty(asset,key,date);
      // PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(asset,key,value); // Also fails for dates
    }else{
        PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(asset,key,value);
    }
} else{
      PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(asset,key,value);
}
```

If I don't use PropertyUtils to update date properties and just call the setter directly (e.g. `asset.setAvailableFrom`) then it works fine.  This is workable solution for me but I'd prefer to use PropertyUtils.

```
if (value instanceof String){
   if ((key.equals("lastUpdatedDate")) || (key.equals("availableFrom")) || (key.equals("availableTo"))|| (key.equals("purchaseDate"))) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ");
        Date date = df.parse((String)value);
        if (key.equals("availableFrom")){
            asset.setAvailableFrom(date); // This works
        }
    }else{
       PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(asset,key,value);
    }
}else{
   PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(asset,key,value);
}
```

Any advice appreciated.

CapitalAsset bean:

```
public class CapitalAsset {

private Date availableFrom;
private Date availableTo;
public String getAvailableFrom(){
    try {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
        return df.format(availableFrom);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}

public void setAvailableFrom(Date availableFrom) {
    this.availableFrom = availableFrom;
}

public String getAvailableTo(){
    try {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
        return df.format(availableTo);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}

public void setAvailableTo(Date availableTo) {
    this.availableTo = availableTo;
}
}
```

Comment: is `com.brightgreenstar.entities.CapitalAsset` contains `availableFrom` or its super class?

Comment: getter for `availableFrom` returns `String`, but setter accepts `Date`, thus this class cannot be properly introspected and assignment fails.

Comment: CapitalAsset contains availableFrom.  Added details to my question.  But looking at my code again I think problem may be that my getter doesn't return date.  I'm going to alter that and test again.

Comment: Thanks @SashaSalauyou about to test that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to include a getter that returns date:

```
    public Date getAvailableFrom(){
    return availableFrom;
}
```